# AutoScroll Android ListView and sync up with Audio file

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I want to create a listview that would automatically scroll based on the playing of an audio file in the background.

Say the audio file is 10 mins long. I will have a list view that contains English translation of the audio playing in a different language. So each list item will have sentence by sentence translation.

I know a listview can be programmatically scrolled to a known position but I'm trying to sync it up with the audio file. If the user click on a list item the audio file should play from the position of the list item.

Any ideas how this can be achieved in the most simplest way?

Answer (score 0):

You might find the `smoothScrollByOffset()` or `smoothScrollBy()` methods of `ListView` most useful.  In particular `smoothScrollBy()` takes both a distance to scroll and a duration over which the scroll animation should take place.  With this method you can control precisely how far to scroll the list.

HTH